# Вызов модального окна через адресную строку

Tags: javascript, css, url

Вопрос нестандартный — можно ли управлять отображением модального окна через адресную строку?
то есть
К примеру есть site.ru
и 2 окна — #modal1 #modal2
стандартный вызов модального окна

```
<button data-target="#modal1" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Модальное окно 1</button>
```

чтобы к примеру зайдя на site.ru/?q=#modal1 сайт открылся с уже показанным окном #modal1 
сайт на чистом HTML

Comment: подключен jQuery Bootstrap

Comment: То что идёт после '#' не передаётся на сервер. Поэтому на чистом HTML сделать не выйдет, необходимо использовать js.

Comment: @Arnial можете тыкнуть носом в пример? на сайте 
 
подключен jQuery и Bootstrap

Comment: Понадобится чистый js :) по document ready проверяйте что в адресной строки и инициируйте попап по необходимости

Comment: @jekaby тыкните носом в примеры пожалуйста) я в JS почти 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите идти таким путем, то лучше всего перехватывать адресную строку через javascript (jquery). Это можно сделать вот так:

```
window.location.href // вся строка
window.location.hash // то, что после #
```

Соответственно:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    // http://example.com - url
    // http://example.com#modal - hash

    if(hash == '#modal'){
        $('.modal').show('slow');
    }
});
```

Как то так.

Comment: Cпасибо огромное!

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк Пожалуйста. Вместо спасибо еще можно отметить ответ как лучший)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ancor = window.location.hash.replace("#","");
    if (ancor == 'modal1') {
        $('#modal1').modal('show');
    }
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо огромное!

Comment: проще уж сразу - `$('#'+ancor).modal('show')`